# Laravel tries to write data to wrong SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm writing an artisan command which scans **.csv** files and writes them to **MySQL database**.

Every new file, I'm overriding Record model with new table name

```
<?php 
    namespace App; 
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
    class Record extends Model { 
    protected $guarded = []; 
    protected $table = 'adjustments';
}
```

But when I execute the command Laravel tries to write new Record's data to the old one's table.

Where I did the mistake?

Comment: How come you're creating a new table for each csv?

Comment: Is adjustment table is right?  Do you want to store data in adjustments table?

Answer (score 0):

Check your .env and config/database.php you probably forgot to change to your new database

Comment: Database stays the same. Just another table.

Comment: How you are saving the new added csv are you using maatwebsite/laravel-excel ?
if you can share the code that you use to save the entries

Comment: did you changed protacted $table ?

Comment: I'm not using any package. I'm reading line by line the file and then I'm using $record->fill(<field name> => <field value>). And in the end just $record->save()

Comment: @AshishPatel yes, it gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use `Schema::rename()` inside your model, like below

```
Schema::rename('records', 'adjustments');
```

If you want to do this inside other than model see below mothod:\

```
$product = new Record;
$product->getTable(); // products
$product->setTable('adjustments');
```

This one will create new table:

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('adjustments', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: But this function renames table. I need new one.

Comment: You want to use create table function inside controller?

Comment: Model always has the right table name, but for some reason Laravel writes to wrong one.

Comment: No no, my command forms new migration and runs it. Then it creates model accordingly to the migration and then writes to database through it.

Comment: It is my own written.

Comment: Please tell me your exact need briefly

Comment: I have bunch of **.csv** files and I need to store it in database. So my program takes the file, scans it, determines field names,  data types of columns and then creates model and table accordingly. After that it reads line by line the file and stores it into database. After that it takes new file and starts over again. Here I get the error where it tries to write to the wrong table and doesn't find required field.